# Use simple Salesforce package to make SOQL calls using custom salesforce URL as a parameter

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am trying to use simple Salesforce python package to make SOQL calls but the salesforce link I am tyring to connect to is a non-prod environment (uat.lightning.force.com). Howerver, I keep running in to "AttributeError" exception.

Do you know guys if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the lightning domain. Use generic test.salesforce.com (unless admin blocked it, you can check in Setup -> My Domain). Or productiondomain--uat.my.salesforce.com.

If you still get errors - check login history and post your connection code?

Comment: I got this resolved. Thanks a lot